# How to call powershell script from powershell script by passing the argument

Tags: powershell

I have script `step1.ps1` & it contains the code:

```
echo "Starting with Step 3: Configuring the OS..."
echo "$args[0] and $args[1]"
step3.ps1 $args[0] $args[1]
```

I execute this script

```
powershell.exe install.ps1 <ip-address> <hostname>
```

Now when `step1.ps1` is executed it calls script `step3.ps1` & it contains the code:

```
echo "checking step3"
echo $args[0] and $args[1]
ac -Encoding UTF8  "$($env:windir)\system32\Drivers\etc\hosts" $args[0] $args[1]
echo "HANA DB Host file entry maintained"
```

It gives me an error:

```
powershell.exe : Add-Content : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument '<hostname>'.  
At line:1 char:1  
+ powershell.exe install.ps1 <ip-address> ...  
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~  
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (Add-Content : A...  
 'vue2dvdbhs5'.:String) [], RemoteException  
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError


At step3.ps1:3 char:1  
+ Add-Content -Value $args[0] $args[1] -Path "$($env:windir)\system32\D ...  
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~  
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Add-Content],  
 ParameterBindingException  
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId :  
 PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.AddContentCommand
```

Comment: Why use the `$args` array when you can use named parameters?

Comment: @Bill_Stewart Probably a newer powershell user with batch background.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is with the `Add-Content` (`ac`) call.  As a best-practice in scripts, I suggest you avoid aliases and always name your parameters:

```
     #Alternative: "$($args[0]) $($args[1])"
     #or           ('{0} {1}' -f $args)
Add-Content -Value ($args[0] + ' ' + $args[1]) -Path "$Env:SystemRoot\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts" -Encoding UTF8
```

The problem is the interpreter is trying to find a positionally-bound parameter that doesn't exist.  It is trying to fill `-Value` with `$args[0]` and find another parameter for `$args[1]`.  In this example, I group them with parens and add a space for the hosts file.

---

Based on your comment:

```
$IP = Test-Connection -ComputerName $Env:ComputerName -Count 1
Add-Content -Value "$($IP.Address) $($IP.IPV4Address)" -Path "$Env:SystemRoot\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts" -Encoding UTF8
```

Comment: Thanks for your patience. Yes, I am beginner in powershell script.
Can you please also suggest how to add the system itslef ip-address & hosts. Below is the code I wrote based on the your reference but it did not work.

$ipV4 = Test-Connection -ComputerName (hostname) -Count 1 
Add-Content -Path "$Env:SystemRoot\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts" -Value "$($ipv4) $($hostname)" -Encoding UTF8

Comment: @hans I've updated my answer with your comment question

Comment: Its only updating the ipaddress but not the hostname along with it

Comment: @hans I made a mistake in which member I was accessing.  I've updated the answer again to address this.  It turns out this cmdlet is just an abstraction of the `Win32_PingStatus` wmi class